# Expansion of a random variable

Tags: proof-verification, random-variables

In the middle of a physics calculation, I am facing the following expression: $$(1+\alpha)^X$$ where $\alpha \ll 1$ and $X$ is a random variable, which I do not know the pdf but assumed smoothly defined.

I am trying to simplify the expectation/average of this expression by expanding using $\alpha \ll 1$. I get $$\langle (1+\alpha)^x \rangle \approx 1+ \alpha \langle X \rangle + \frac12 \alpha^2 \langle X \rangle^2 + \frac12 \alpha^2 {\rm std}(X)^2 + O(\alpha^3) $$

I would like to know if it is normal to not see a first order dependence in ${\rm std}(X)$ the standard deviation of $X$. To be honest, that would have matched my expectation.

Comment: In principle you wouldn't see first order in std because std is of order $\sqrt{E[X^2]}$, which is not a polynomial in terms of $X,X^2$.

Comment: @AlexR. Yeah, that is good reason.